Why would my Expo app not be able to access my local server API, but ping and Postman can?
I want my Expo app to make API requests to a local development server. When I attempt to make API requests, I get Network Request Failed. I am running the server from a Docker container in WSL. The server is accesible to an AngularJS client (also a Docker container in WSL), Postman (Windows), and regular ping, but not the Expo app (WSL).
I have made sure to use the IPv4 address instead of "localhost" in my Expo app and verified via Postman and telnet that the IP address and port are accessible. The URI for the API request is identical to the one in the Postman request and has the same information in the body:
// constants.js
export const API_URL = "http://172.18.114.140:80/api/";

import { API_URL } from "../util/constants";

// For connecting to localhost backend
async function getToken(username, password) {
  try {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
   
  const response = await fetch(API_URL + "login/", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: { "username": username, "password": password }
  });
  console.log("response 1" ,response);
  const result = await response.json();
  return result;
  }
  catch (error) {
   console.log("getToken: ", error.message)
}

...


const { token: devToken } = await getToken("username", "password")

Postman API call with body content omitted:

The only difference in the Postman API call is 9 auto-generated headers, which I believe the absence of should not affect the Expo app being able to reach the API.
I have tried to forward the port from WSL using VS Code Port Forwarding so my Expo app can make API requests to it, but I cannot change the visibility of the port to public because the column is not there.

I believe I need to authenticate using my GitHub credentials (worked on my Mac in order to get the Visibility column), but the page to authenticate with SSO does not appear.
I have tried to add a port in VS Code to trigger the SSO authentication, but it does not appear. While I am developing on Windows, but I tried this on my Mac and was able to forward a port, authenticate, and then change the visibility.
